# How to fix the variations of a word occurring in a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to identify and rectify the variations of a word occurring in a column?

E.g. Came across a LinkedIn post that mentioned a dataset that had the city `Philadelphia spelled in 57 different ways`, and asked data scientists on their views to approach this data quality issue.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

place = ['PHIADELPHIA','PHIALDELPHIA','PHIDELPHIA','illinois','PHIELADELPHIA','PHIILADELPHIA','illinoi','PHILA','PHILA.','PHILAD','PHILADALPHIA','PHILADELPHIA','PHILADELAPHIA','PHILADELHIA','PHILADELHPIA','PHILADELLPHIA','PHILADELPHIA','PHILADELPH','PHILADELPHA','PHILADELPHAI','PHILADELPHI','PHILADELPHIA']
correct_place=[np.nan]*len(place)
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(place,correct_place), columns=["place", "correct_place"])
```

[image]

How to solve this kind of data cleaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

place = ['PHIADELPHIA','PHIALDELPHIA','PHIDELPHIA','illinois','PHIELADELPHIA','PHIILADELPHIA','illinoi','PHILA','PHILA.','PHILAD','PHILADALPHIA','PHILADELPHIA','PHILADELAPHIA','PHILADELHIA','PHILADELHPIA','PHILADELLPHIA','PHILADELPHIA','PHILADELPH','PHILADELPHA','PHILADELPHAI','PHILADELPHI','PHILADELPHIA']
df = pd.DataFrame({"place": place})
```

Here is one way to do it with [SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) from Python standard library's difflib module:

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def fix(name, correct_names):
    """Helper function.
    
    Args:
        name: string to fix.
        correct_names: list of correct names (strings) of cities.
    
    Returns:
        fixed name or None.
    
    """
    for correct_name in correct_names:
        if SequenceMatcher(None, name.lower(), correct_name).ratio() > 0.5:
            return correct_name
    return pd.NA


correct_places = ("illinois", "philadelphia")
df["correct_place"] = df["place"].apply(lambda x: fix(x, correct_places))
```

Then:

```py
            place correct_place
0     PHIADELPHIA  philadelphia
1    PHIALDELPHIA  philadelphia
2      PHIDELPHIA  philadelphia
3        illinois      illinois
4   PHIELADELPHIA  philadelphia
5   PHIILADELPHIA  philadelphia
6         illinoi      illinois
7           PHILA  philadelphia
8          PHILA.  philadelphia
9          PHILAD  philadelphia
10   PHILADALPHIA  philadelphia
11   PHILADELPHIA  philadelphia
12  PHILADELAPHIA  philadelphia
13    PHILADELHIA  philadelphia
14   PHILADELHPIA  philadelphia
15  PHILADELLPHIA  philadelphia
16   PHILADELPHIA  philadelphia
17     PHILADELPH  philadelphia
18    PHILADELPHA  philadelphia
19   PHILADELPHAI  philadelphia
20    PHILADELPHI  philadelphia
21   PHILADELPHIA  philadelphia
```